# Uncaught TypeError: Type error when using onload

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload

Ok I am stuck. I am trying to insert an image into a canvas and Chrome keeps giving me Uncaught TypeError: Type error for the onload method. Here is my javascript:

```
letterBase = new Image();
letterBase.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(letterBase, 0, 0);
    console.log("drawing image");
  };
  letterBase.src = "/assets/letter/" + Character.letter + ".png";
  console.log(letterBase);
```

It is weird because I can see that the image is loading in the console from console.log(letterBase) but I really don't see what is going wrong here. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit: I don't think this is where the problem lies, but I have the code setting up the context as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // some other init functions...
    canvas = document.getElementById("characterCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // ...
```

Comment: did you set `context` as 2d canvas context

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434371/image-onload-function-with-return

Comment: @mgraph yes, when I initiated the canvas.

Comment: @ryan: How is this a duplicate of that question? The code is different in fundamental ways.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder letterBase.onload

Comment: to be more specific though the error comes on the line after that

Comment: @TravMcKinney: I'd suggest showing your code setting up `context`. Good luck with it, I'm off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. After setting the source and loading the images I was clearing the variable

```
letterBase.src = ""
```

which was causing the onload to fire a second time but this time with no source. Noob mistake.