# How to get width of an image picked from input type file

Tags: jquery, html, image

I need a **JQuery** function that return height and width of an image picked from a **input type file**.
I found this function on Stackoverflow:

```
function getImageWidth(elemento){       
    $.fileImmagine = elemento;      
    var fr = new FileReader;
    // file is loaded    
    fr.onload = function() { 
        var img = new Image;    
        img.onload = function() {           
            alert(img.width);                   
        };
        // is the data URL because called with 
        img.src = fr.result; readAsDataURL
    }; 
    // I'm using a <input type="file"> for demonstrating   
    fr.readAsDataURL($($.fileImmagine)[0].files[0]);    
}
```

I don't understand how I can edit this function, in order to turn `alert(img.width)` into `return img.width`.

How can I "tell" the function to return the width of the image only after the image i loaded?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image.onload function with return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434371/image-onload-function-with-return)

Comment: returning height and width of image after uploading - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAwzaG  Hope this works for you